# Cartesian product in racket (Is append-map okay?)

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I've read several places that say it's really bad to use `append`, and I understand why. I read somewhere that it was never even correct to use `append`. However, I was working on a textbook exercise in *Essentials of Programming Languages* (Ex 1.21 pg27) that asked me to write a Cartesian product function. I couldn't think of any other easy way than using `append-map`. Below is my working solution to the exercise. Is there a better more idiomatic way of writing this? Thanks!

```lisp
; product : Listof(SchemeVal) -> Listof(SchemeVal) -> Listof(List(SchemeVal))
; usage: (product '(a b c) '(x y)) -> '((a x) (a y) (b x) (b y) (c x) (c y))
(define (product lox loy)
  (append-map (lambda (x) (scalar x loy)) lox))
(define (scalar x loy)
  (map (lambda (y) (list x y)) loy))
```

Comment: Is this code copied verbatim from the text-book? How would it be used?

Comment: No this is my original code... Isn't copying other code against the terms of CR? And the usage is in the comment.

Comment: Yes it is, hence the question. Thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: No problem, sorry for the confusion. I've edited my question to make it more clear the code is mine, and where the question came from.